# Why does it make the composite amplifier circuit stable?

Tags: amplifier

I reversed engineered a headphone amplifier based on composite topology with opa1612 and tpa6120a2.

There's two capacitor and one resistor (circled in red) that I don't quite understand. I know this is for stabilizing the circuit, but don't understand the theory behind it. could someone give some hints/pointers to help me understand it? Thanks!

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: I'd argue that the top 560p cap is useless. Google "In-the-loop compensation" to understand how the caps from output to inverting input improve stability. It is needed for fast opamps like the opa1612 or when you have high feedback impedances.

Comment: Thank you so much @tobalt! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: For composite amp to work properly, the driving amp (TPA6120A2) must be faster than the low noise op amp (OPA1612). A single 220pF may be just enough to reduce the Opa bandwidth.
L30 first gen seems to have oscillation issue, so beware when using this exact circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the circuit does not have oscillation issue, as can be verified by simulation. The first version failed because 1) poor ESD design 2) incorrect DC protection circuit.

Answer (score 2):

After a year I believe I can answer the question myself.
The circuit is based on some topology called Transitional Miller Compensation. In this case, the compensation is also enclosing the input stage. See for example [this doc](https://www.data-odyssey.nl/Super_TIS.html).

This is just one way to make the composite amplifier circuit stable. There're other ways to achieve that for sure, such as the "in the loop compensation" @tobalt has pointed out, which leaves the left 560p cap.